# How do you setup an rsync server and client?

Tags: rsync

I have worked on rsync for the whole afternoon.
I have set a rsync server,but I don't know how to use it.

I have two machines:66 and 12.
66 is the server,I want to back 66's data to 12,so I use rsync.

I have done the following:

**In 66:**

```
sudo apt-get install xinetd 

sudo vim /etc/xinetd.d/rsync 
service rsync 
    { 
        disable         = no 
        socket_type     = stream 
        wait            = no 
        user            = root 
        server          = /usr/bin/rsync 
        server_args     = --daemon 
        log_on_failure  += USERID 
    } 

sudo nano  /etc/rsyncd.conf 

max connections = 2 
log file = /var/log/rsync.log 
timeout = 300 

  [wwwroot] 
  comment = Public Share 
  path = /home/wwwroot 
  read only = no 
  list = yes 
  uid = nobody 
  gid = nogroup 
  auth userusers = user 
  secrets file = /home/rsync.secrets

sudo /etc/init.d/xinetd restart
```

**in 12:**

```
rsync -v  user@192.168.1.100::wwwroot  /home/young001/backup --password-file=/home/rsync.pass
```

and it tells:

```
skipping directory .

sent 4 bytes  received 6 bytes  2.86 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

the log is:

```
2013/06/12 03:18:18 [30477] name lookup failed for 125.221.225.12: Name or service not known
2013/06/12 03:18:18 [30477] connect from UNKNOWN (125.221.225.12)
2013/06/12 10:18:18 [30477] rsync on ctp/ from young001@UNKNOWN (125.221.225.12)
2013/06/12 10:18:18 [30477] building file list
2013/06/12 10:18:18 [30477] skipping directory .
2013/06/12 10:18:18 [30477] sent 98 bytes  received 54 bytes  total size 0
2013/06/12 03:19:59 [30484] name lookup failed for 125.221.225.12: Name or service not known
2013/06/12 03:19:59 [30484] connect from UNKNOWN (125.221.225.12)
2013/06/12 10:19:59 [30484] rsync on ctp/ from young001@UNKNOWN (125.221.225.12)
2013/06/12 10:19:59 [30484] building file list
2013/06/12 10:19:59 [30484] skipping directory .
2013/06/12 10:19:59 [30484] sent 98 bytes  received 54 bytes  total size 0
```

it seems to tell that the directory is empty,but I don't know which directory is empty.

/home/young001/backup is a empty directory,and /home/wwwroot is not a empty directory.

I want to sync wwwroot to backup,so where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use "a" or another rsync option to actually do something other than checking:

```
rsync -av  user@192.168.1.......
```

By the way, you can simply use rsync and ssh for the job without installig an rsync server.

Comment: More specifically, it's hitting a directory at the top level and stopping because it was not told to run recursively. The `-a` flag implies recursive, but it's not failing because it is just checking. (That would be `-n`, `--dry-run`.)